# How to use "which" with regex, or other ways to find a command in the $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I am looking for a command, and I want to use regex for finding it.

So, something like this

```
>>> which -a "e?grep"
/bin/grep
/bin/egrep
```

Any workarounds are also appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in another question you can [list all commands and functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94775/list-all-commands-that-a-shell-knows) using `compgen`, thus making the task a trivial matter of which regex engine or command do you want to use.

An example listing EVERYTHING you could possible run:

`$ compgen -A function -abck | grep '.*grep.*'
egrep
fgrep
grep
egrep
fgrep
grep
lzfgrep
fgrep
lzgrep
zstdgrep
zfgrep
bzgrep
plugreport
pcregrep
lzegrep
msggrep
grep
pgrep
zegrep
zgrep
egrep
xzegrep
zipgrep
xzgrep
xzfgrep
pcre2grep
orc-bugreport
ptargrep
ptargrep`

See mentioned question for further information and other available listings. Credit to user Rahul Patil.

Answer (score 1):

Just search in `$PATH` variable:

```
find $(tr : ' ' <<<"$PATH") -type f -executable | egrep "/[e]?grep$"
```

First I find all the executable files in PATH directories, then I egrep with your regex.
The command outputs:

```
/usr/bin/egrep
/usr/bin/grep
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer extends [Kamil Cuk's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50984364/6770384). Improvements:

- Support `$PATH` containing spaces and linebreaks.
- Do *not* search subdirectories of `$PATH`.

Script:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Search a program using an extended regex.
# usage: thisScript extendedRegex 

IFS=: read -d '' -a patharray < <(printf %s "$PATH")

find "${patharray[@]}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable \
     -regextype egrep -regex ".*/$1"
```

Your regex must match the whole command name, similar to `grep -x`.

Possible changes:

- To also match parts of command names, change `-regex ".*/$1"` to `-regex ".*/.*$1.*"`. However, `^` and `$` will not work with this change.
- For case-insensitive search, change `-regex` to `-iregex`.
- To use another regex style, change `egrep` accordingly. `find -regextype help` prints all supported regex types.
- To print only the command names instead of full paths, append `-printf '%f\n'`.